# How to get flexbox flex item figures to wrap when they contain text other than figcaptions

Tags: css, flexbox

The layout has a series of image with captions and then further text underneath. When it is just the caption, the images wrap according to `flex: auto;` rules, which is what I intended. When I add enough text that it is wider than the image, the image then takes up the whole width of the screen no matter how wide it is.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/kimholder/pen/NdbwoW?editors=1100). I tried wrapping the `<p>` elements in `<div>` and styling them with `display: inline;` but it didn't help. Nor did wrapping the text in just a `<span>` element. I have shown the parent elements with flexbox styling as I'm not sure if that impacts the result. How can I get those figures to continue to use their `flex: auto;` dimensions?

The behaviour is visible in the code snippet if you click 'full page'.

```css
html {
  color: #f7f7dc;
  background: black;
 }

section {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  flex: 3 0 350px;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  margin-left: 6vw; }


.outerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 2rem;}

.innerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.6);
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 15px; }
  .innerDiv p {
    padding: 6px 18px 0 15px; }

.pixWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 15px; }
  .pixWrap div p {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px; }

.pix {
  margin: 1vw;
  flex: auto;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #505000; }
  .pix img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; }

figcaption {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.1rem;
  text-align: right;
  width: 90%; }
```

```html
  <section>
    <div class="outerDiv">
      <div class="innerDiv">
        <div class="pixWrap">
          <figure class="pix">
            <img src="http://www.moonwards.com/img/kreep.jpg">
            <figcaption>Map of nighttime soil temperatures
            </figcaption>
            <div>
              <p>
                Large rocks stores heat better than small grains. 
              </p>
            </div>
          </figure>
          <figure class="pix">
            <img src="http://www.moonwards.com/img/NightTempLalande.png">
            <figcaption>Evening image of the colony site by the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter.
            </figcaption>
            <div>
              <p>
                This image shows how the density of the regolith (the soil) changes with depth. BUNCH OF EXTRA TEXT, BUNCH OF EXTRA TEXT, LALALALALALALALALALALALAAL
              </p>
            </div>
          </figure>

          <figure class="pix">
            <img src="http://www.moonwards.com/img/Teacup250.jpg" alt="Lalande Crater east wall
      below rim Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter image at noon showing
      flows of debris and depth of stony outcroppings">
            <figcaption>Noon image near the colony site. Also by the LRO,
            </figcaption>
            what happens if i do this? 
          </figure>
          <figure class="pix">
            <img src="http://www.moonwards.com/img/Thumb-Lunar_Thorium_hotspots.jpg">
            <figcaption>captions coming</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <figure class="pix">
            <img src="http://www.moonwards.com/img/Lal-boulders1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Can you simply use `figure { max-width: 200px; }` where `200px` is whatever works for your UI?

Comment: @MichaelCoker hm, i suppose i could add a max-width for each figure as an inline style. Each image has its own dimensions. That didn't occur to me.  I thought this might have a more general solution. (The images in the real page are much larger than the examples.)